# autograd differentiation example in PyTorch - should be 9/8?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent, autograd

In the [example for the Torch tutorial for Python](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html), they use the following graph:

```
x = [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
y = x + 2
z = 3y^2
o = mean( z )  # 1/4 * x.sum()
```

Thus, the forward pass gets us this:

```
x_i = 1, y_i = 3, z_i = 27, o = 27
```

In code this looks like:

```py
import torch

# define graph
x = torch.ones(2, 2, requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = y * y * 3
out = z.mean()

# if we don't do this, torch will only retain gradients for leaf nodes, ie: x
y.retain_grad()
z.retain_grad()

# does a forward pass
print(z, out)
```

however, I get confused at the gradients computed:

```py
# now let's run our backward prop & get gradients
out.backward()
print(f'do/dz = {z.grad[0,0]}')
```

which outputs:

```
do/dx = 4.5
```

By chain rule, `do/dx = do/dz * dz/dy * dy/dx`, where:

```
dy/dx = 1
dz/dy = 9/2 given x_i=1
do/dz = 1/4 given x_i=1
```

which means:

```
do/dx = 1/4 * 9/2 * 1 = 9/8
```

However this doesn't match the gradients returned by Torch (9/2 = 4.5). Perhaps I have a math error (something with the do/dz = 1/4 term?), or I don't understand `autograd` in Torch.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do/dz = 1 / 4
dz/dy = 6y = 6 * 3 = 18
dy/dx = 1
```

therefore, do/dx = 9/2

Comment: Oh geez. I clearly need to review freshman calculus.....thanks! Looks like Torch works juuuust fine.